# Take string and everything after

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I want to get a certain string from a column and return that string and everything to the right. How can this be accomplished? I'm using the following right now but this does the opposite of what I want. It removes the data and keeps everything before the string 'abc'. I need to keep the string 'abc' and everything to the right.

```
when column1like '%abc%' then left(column1, CHARINDEX('abc', column1) -1) 
                         else column1
```

Comment: You'll find that you get more answers if you upvote the correct answers. You can also mark answers as accepted if they solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `stuff()`:

```
(case when column1 like '%abc%'
      then stuff(column1, 1, charindex('abc', column1), '')
      . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do a RIGHT with a LEN function, give this a go;

```
when column1like '%abc%' then right(column1, len(column1)-(CHARINDEX('abc', column1) +2)) else column1
```